# how to sue Facebook SDK login dialog box in my app without opening safari or any other browser?

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, window, facebook-login

I want to use facebook sdk for log in to my app. On clicking the facebook log in button it is navigating to safari browser, but my app requirement is to show facebook log in flow in a window ( dialog box ).

Comment: First, it's sure a good thing to sue Facebook for anything ;-)

Comment: Im not a 100% sure but I think with the new Graph API 2.0 this is the standard behavior an cannot be changed. But this process can also be implemented into a flow quite nicely.

Comment: u don't need to open with safari , u need only open the login with inside the app using popupwindow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u need to open the Facebook login with in dialog box u do follow ur steps

1. open ur app.plist file
2. select the `URL type`s with a single array sub-item called `URL Schemes`
3. remove or delete the value of   the `URL Schemes` item 0
4. clean your project run agin ,completed

[image]

Comment: is it is working now. Dialog box is open with facebook log in.Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIwebview controller and open Facebook in your App.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use  UIWebView to opne facebook in your apps

Comment: that is pretty much a duplicate of the answer from sumit sharma...